# What is this 15 pins connector?

Tags: port, connector, game-controller

[image: Old game controller]

I do not think it's a serial port as there's too much pins. It's used to plug a very old controller. Will I be able to find any adapter to USB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will I be able to find any adapter to USB?

Yes

> I do not think it's a serial port as there's too much pins.  It's used to plug a very old controller.

It's a game port connector

> The game port, originally introduced on the Game Control Adapter, is a
> device port that was found on IBM PC compatible and other computer
> systems throughout the 1980s and 1990s. It was the traditional
> connector for joystick input, and occasionally MIDI devices, until
> replaced by USB in the 21st century.
>
> [image]

Source: [Game Port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_port)

Comment: Actually there is an adapter....https://www.amazon.com/Rockfire-game-Adapter-RM-203-gameport/dp/B004HAX7OU